# Leitura de PDF em R

Tags: r, pdf

Estou efetuando um trabalho para a faculdade e gostaria obter a renda e o público de cada jogo do campeonato brasileiro dos últimos anos. A CBF diponibiliza em uma série de links, um exemplo é o [Borderô](https://conteudo.cbf.com.br/sumulas/2014/1421b.pdf). Para outros problemas parecidos eu uso o pacote `tabulizer`, como no código abaixo

```
library(tabulizer)
url <- 'https://conteudo.cbf.com.br/sumulas/2014/1421b.pdf'
d <- extract_tables(url, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Para tabelas criadas em PDF ele funciona perfeitamente, mas para este tipo de pdf (que provavelmente foi impresso, escaneado e depois salvo em pdf) não funciona, o código retorna uma lista com 0 elementos. Alguma ideia ou pacote que eu possa utilizar?

Comment: `@Flavio Silva` nesse caso o problem não é extrair dados de um pdf, mas extrair dados da imagem. Veja que não há qualquer estrutura neste pdf, só a imagem. Você precisa de algum programa que extraia textos de imagens.

Answer (score 3):

A tabela que consta no PDF, trata-se de uma imagem. Esse pacote do R busca por elementos textuais, ele retorna uma lista vazia justamente por isso, porque não há texto no arquivo. Você necessita de técnicas que façam reconhecimento de texto em imagem, eu sugiro que você busque por OCR, que é um processo que extrai texto de uma dada imagem.

No R, há o pacote tesseract, o qual realiza esse operação.
Segue o link de um tutorial do pacote Tesseract do R, que faz a extração de texto de imagem.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tesseract/vignettes/intro.html

Nesta parte do tutorial ele mostra como extrair de um PDF

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tesseract/vignettes/intro.html#read_from_pdf_files

Comment: Lerei, muito obrigado pela resposta!